# Including an attribute of an unrelated element in an XPath

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have the following XML file:

```
<phonebook>
    <departments>
        <department id="1" parent="" title="Rabit Hole" address="" email="" index=""/>
        <department id="2" parent="" title="Big Pond" address="" email="" index=""/>
    </departments>
    <employees>
        <employee id="1" fname="Daffy" lname="Duck" title="Admin" email="daffy.duck@example.com" department="2" room="" />
        <employee id="2" fname="Bugs" lname="Bunny" title="Programmer" email="bugs.bunny@example.com" department="1" room="" />
    </employees>
</phonebook>
```

When displaying it, I want to show the contact details for an employee as well as the title of the department where he works. Here's what I've got in the template:

```
<xsl:for-each select="phonebook/employees/employee">
    <xsl:sort select="@lname" />
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="lname"><xsl:value-of select="@lname"/></span>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <span class="fname"><xsl:value-of select="@fname"/></span>
        </td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@title"/></td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="/phonebook/departments/department[@id='{@department}']/@title"/>
        </td>
        <td><a href="mailto:{@email}"><xsl:value-of select="@email"/></a></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The problem is that the following rule doesn't seem to work:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/phonebook/departments/department[@id='{@department}']/@title"/>
```

I guess this is because the XSLT engine looks for the `department` property in the `department` element, and not in the `employee` element. However, I don't have an idea how to fix it. Could anyone give me a hint on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of ways, but a nice reusable one is to use a [**key**](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_key.asp).

Definition:

```
<xsl:key name="dept" match="/phonebook/departments/department" use="@id"/>
```

Usage (where the current node is an `<employee>`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('dept', @department)/@title"/>
```

Comment: Please, *simplify* your <xsl:key>. One can use just: match="department" . As a matter of fact, the value of the "match" attribute is a *match pattern*, something quite simpler than a more complete XPath expression.

Answer (score 2):

The {} in the select are not supported, I prefer using a variable, but anothor option would be using current(). But I would probably just use something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="departmentId" select="@department" />
<xsl:value-of select="/phonebook/departments/department[@id=$departmentId]/@title"/>
```

Comment: Doh! I tried using a variable, and it didn't work. But copy-pasted from your example, it does. Thanks! :)